# Trying to match the year in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex

I want to be able to take an array of strings:

Here is the mock data that I am using.

```js
const archives = {
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Employee Engagement Summary",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2018",
                "date_range": "03/01/2018-05/15/2018",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 1",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2017",
                "date_range": "03/01/2017-05/15/2017",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 2",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2016",
                "date_range": "03/01/2016-05/15/2016",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2015",
                "date_range": "03/01/2015-05/15/2015",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
    ]
};

export default archives;
```

the above code is having the real mock data that i am using.

And just extract the year out of it. Because I want to be able to iterate through the years and place them on a list

```html
<ul>
  <li>2018</li>
  <li>2017</li>
  <li>2016</li>
  <li>2015</li>
  <li>2014</li>
  <li>2013</li>
  <li>2012</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Is the additional f on line 3 a typo?

Comment: It gets boring some times...when e.g. as here, where all the answers gets downvoted and no real explanation. How does that play with SO's down vote privilege, saying: _"Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Instead of voting down:

If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it."_

Comment: See [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed)

Comment: @Bucket I posted the actual mock data I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var archives = {
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Employee Engagement Summary",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2018",
                "date_range": "03/01/2018-05/15/2018",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 1",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2017",
                "date_range": "03/01/2017-05/15/2017",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 2",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2016",
                "date_range": "03/01/2016-05/15/2016",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2015",
                "date_range": "03/01/2015-05/15/2015",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var yearsRange = archives.data.map(obj => obj.attributes.date_range);

var yearArr= [];

yearsRange.filter(item => {
   yearArr.push(item.split('/')[2].split('-')[0]);
});

console.log("yearArr", yearArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just  match on four digits, at least for your case

`(str => str.match(/\d{4}/)[0])`

```js
var dateStrings = [
  "March 21, 2018",
  "March 21, 2017f",
  "March 21, 2016",
  "March 21, 2015",
  "March 21, 2014",
  "March 21, 2013",
  "March 21, 2012"
];
var years = dateStrings.map(str => str.match(/\d{4}/)[0]);
var ul = years.reduce((ul, year) => {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = year;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  return ul;
}, document.createElement('ul'));

document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: yea, nearly the same

Comment: So much easier than what everyone else is suggesting

Comment: @JuanMendes So how is that easier, doing 2 loops, one _map_ and then one _forEach_? ... In mine I use only one loop, much more efficient.

Comment: @LGSon The main point is the regex, 4 digits is really easy to read and doesn't require you to match two things (assuming more about the input) . This has nothing to do with efficiency, but how easy it is to read the code. I don't see any performance bottleneck here and I think the elegance of functional programming won't cost you anything noticeable. But again, not the point of the question. _"Trying to match the year in a string in javascript"_

Comment: @JuanMendes Given that users here will take an answers upvoted/working code and use it in their own code, where it might matter, doing 2 loops, so why would one want to award that?

Comment: @LGSon Because of the elegance of functional programming. It's two separate things: string processing and HTML creation that can be computed separately. I could rewrite it without touching the code that gets the dates out (the point of the question) If there's a bottleneck, it's different. Premature optimization is the root of all evil :p

Comment: @JuanMendes Not disagree and not against elegant programming, though I like when stuff like that is explained, performance against elegance ... and I do agree that the regex is both good and easy to read.

Comment: @colorgreen I posted the actual mock data I am using.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = [
  "March 21, 2018",
  "March 21, 2017f",
  "March 21, 2016",
  "March 21, 2015",
  "March 21, 2014",
  "March 21, 2013",
  "March 21, 2012"
]; 

//Array to hold the years
let years = [];

//Iterate your date collection
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    //Split the string on the comma
    const splitter = str[i].split(",");

    //If the split produces more than one string value, meaning we have a formatted date
    if(splitter.length > 1){
       //Replace any non digit characters and trim whitespace
       let year = splitter[1].replace(/\D/g,'').trim();
       //push year value into new array
       years.push(year);

    }
}

//View the results in console
console.log(years);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can split on the `,` if your strings are always in the same format. I used the regex `/[^0-9]/gi` to replace anything that is not a number in the year with a non-character `''`. Which prevents things like `2017f` from including the f.

```js
var dates = [
  "March 21, 2018",
  "March 21, 2017f",
  "March 21, 2016",
  "March 21, 2015",
  "March 21, 2014",
  "March 21, 2013",
  "March 21, 2012"
]; 

const years = [];
for(const date of dates){
  const year = date.split(',')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').trim();
  years.push(year);
}

console.log(years);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use matches and check for 4 digits: `/\d{4}/`

```js
var str = [
  "March 21, 2018",
  "March 21, 2017f",
  "March 21, 2016",
  "March 21, 2015",
  "March 21, 2014",
  "March 21, 2013",
  "March 21, 2012"
];

let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

str.forEach(date => {
  let matches = date.match(/\d{4}/)
  matches.length > 0 ? (ul.innerHTML += `<li>${matches[0]}</li>`) : null
})
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: [Nenad Vracar already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310831/3832970) the same answer. Also, it does not work for the second item, `"March 21, 2017f"`